# Android Preview Not Translating to Emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Now I've already browsed some similar threads, and they helped a bit but I still can't figure this out. I just started Android developing a couple hours ago and I'm following along in this video series, but in the videos the preview matches the emulator exactly. Mine does not. I've attached my xml (however I've been doing this by dragging and dropping on the design tab as that's how the video has been doing it and I know next to nothing about xml coding). The imgur link here has my graphical issue depicted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K95G.jpg I would appreciate some advice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Click the button of the larger number. Not hard guy"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.359"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="Bigger Number Game!"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="13dp"
        tools:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        android:onClick="leftButtonClick"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="211dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:onClick="rightButtonClick"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:text="Points: 0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tools` namespace, which you use in your title TextView, is only used by the design editor. Those attributes are removed at compile-time and so aren't used in the actual app.

You should use `android:textSize="30sp"` for the text size.

You should set a top constraint for the TextView (`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`) and then set a top margin (`android:layout_marginTop="13dp"`)

Comment: Thanks, so how do I avoid these tools things from appearing? Am I just going to have to look at what appears in the code based on what I drag and drop from the design and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Just don't use `tools`. `android` namespace fields will still appear in the design editor. `tools` is used to reflect programmatic settings in the preview.